# Google Maps Geocode - Wildcard searches beyond exact matches

Tags: google-maps, maps, geocoding

Anyone know if the Google Maps Geocoding service can return results including locations that start with the search term when it finds an exact match for the search term?

Here's my example

In Australia if I search for the term "Bass", I get exactly one result because there is one town in Australia called Bass. But I also want to include any other town that may start with Bass - EG "Bass Hill" and "Bassendean".

I haven't found a reference or example - any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't see any way to do this.

Found this from google geocoding reference.

```
How should I format my geocoder queries to maximise the number of successful requests?

The geocoder is designed to map street addresses to geographical coordinates. We therefore recommend that you format geocoder requests in accordance with the following guidelines to maximise the likelihood of a successful query:

    * Specify addresses in accordance with the format used by the national postal service of the country concerned.
    * Do not specify additional address elements such as business names, unit numbers, floor numbers, or suite numbers that are not included in the address as defined by the postal service of the country concerned.
    * Use the street number of a premise in preference to the building name where possible.
    * Use street number addressing in preference to specifying cross streets where possible.
    * Do not provide 'hints' such as nearby landmarks.
```

Now, given above it(google geocoding webservice) isn't going to assume the inputs given by you for some other input. It tries to map the inputs given by you to the street address, city, country or something else like that.